# C# Need to pass an array of array's to another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to pass an array of arrays to another Form

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[4];
arrayOfStrings[0] = td1stcolumn[];
arrayOfStrings[1] = td2ndcolumn[];
arrayOfStrings[2] = td3rdcolumn[];
arrayOfStrings[3] = td4thcolumn[];
string resultDialogString = ResultDialog.ShowBox(arrayOfStrings, "Result Page");
```

td1stcolumn, td2ndcolumn, td3rdcolumn and td4thcolumn are all String arrays

C# is expecting values in the [] for td...column

Signature of ResultDialog.ShowBox is

```
public static string ShowBox(string[] arrayOfMessages, string txtTitle)
```

but I can modify the signature. I just need to transfer the data from the

td1stcolumn, td2ndcolumn, td3rdcolumn and td4thcolumn

to the ResultDialog.Show method

Comment: I need to pass data from td1stcolumn, td2ndcolumn, td3rdcolumn and td4thcolumn to a form that accepts an array.

Comment: Where is you problem? And show the signature of `ResultDialog.ShowBox`

Comment: And how do you expect to put `string[]` into `string[]`? That can't work, since a `string` isn't `string[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have declared your "td" variables like this:

```
string[] td1stcolumn;
string[] td2ndcolumn;
string[] td3rdcolumn;
string[] td4thcolumn;
```

Then you can assign these values to your `arrayOfStrings` like this:

```
arrayOfStrings[0] = td1stcolumn;
arrayOfStrings[1] = td2ndcolumn;
arrayOfStrings[2] = td3rdcolumn;
arrayOfStrings[3] = td4thcolumn;
```

You'll also need to change the declaration for your string array to something like this:

```
// an array of arrays.  Each array must be the same length.
// your situation calls for a jagged array though.
string[,] arrayOfStrings;
```

or

```
// jagged array. each array can be of varying length.
string[][] arrayOfSTrings;
```

[Multi-Dimentional Array Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

[Jagged Array Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)

Example of a Jagged Array usage:

```
string[][] arr = new string[2][];

arr[0] = new [] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
arr[1] = new [] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

Comment: do I say String[,] arrayOfArrays = new String[1,4];

Comment: In this case it must be a jagged array since he assigns preexisting 1D arrays.

Comment: @orange.  Yes.  You'll need to make sure all your 'td' arrays are the same length (4 in your example).  If they aren't, use a jagged array.

Comment: They are all the same length. If one is 4, then all are 4.

Comment: I just tried this in VS.  A Jagged array is the way you want to go, as CodeInChaos said.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be better suited to a multidimension array...

```
// declare
String[,] multiArray = new String[4,4];

// use
string s = multiArray[2,2];
```